# Creating listener for new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to perform an action for every element with class `box`, but I don't want to wait for a document to load.

I'd rather set a listener that would catch all new elements of this class on the fly.

```
<script src="js.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

How can I do it without using `$.ready` inside `js.js`?

I think in jQuery it would be something like:

```
$(document).on("load", '.box', myfunc);
```

But how to achieve it in plain JS?

Comment: Try [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but note browser compatibility

Comment: So are these `div`s added dynamically?

Comment: No, they are not. But I want to put JS in the head, not before </body>. Also, I want to perform my action right away, without waiting for document to load.

Comment: You can add eventListener on `document` or `window` to register events. Also if you do not want to wait for load, you can look into `DOMContentLoad`

Comment: So you want to perform an action when every single 'box' div rendered? Is it correct?

Comment: @JuneyoungOh Look at my example code. It should trigger my action for every `box` element, one at a time, during document loading, not at the end.

Comment: You can add custom event and fire it when element load.

Answer (score -2):

Simplest and certain way is using native `load` event.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simplest version with native</title>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', function(){
                alert('Do what ever you want!');
                var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
                // Do what you want with boxes
            }, false);
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='box1'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this doesn't do what OP is asking

Comment: Thanks, but I DON'T want to wait for a whole document to load. Your answer does not help me.